# How do I copy `~/Music` from `Terminal` to ensure the files continue to be expected where they are?

Tags: mac, audio, rsync, itunes, music

On a new Macbook Pro, I run `sudo rm -fr ~/Music` and then drag using `Finder` the folder `~/Music` from my old MBp to `~/.` on the new mac.

The meta data are intact (phew!), but
[Get info](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252291105?answerId=254504768022#254504768022)
shows that the `Music` app is expecting each music file to be at

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/<artist>/<song>
```

but the actual file after copying remains where it was at:

```
~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/<artist>/<song>
```

How do I copy `~/Music` from `Terminal` to ensure the files continue to be expected where they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what changed the references during a `Finder` copy, but I can confirm that running

```
rsync -avz /Volumes/ExternalDisk/Music  ~/. >> /tmp/musiclog 2>&1
```

works. It takes exactly 10 times as long as a straight `Finder` copy, but everything is fine afterwards:

- Playlists, both smart and manually set, are intact.
- Play counts, ratings, and "loved" songs are intact.
- The cover images take a few minutes to repopulate, but they are then visible at the expected resolution.
- .. and of course the files, both those in lossless as well as those in a lossy format, are intact.

Only one detail remains: confirming it's possible to sync the music collection on an iPhone and an iPad to the new MBp, replacing the old MBp, but that's a separate issue.

Another issue is that the attributes after an rsync are not exactly the same as they are when a new user is created on macOS. You can see the discrepancy in the following directory fragment.

```
  drwx------  10 sam    staff    310 Feb 12  2021 Music
  drwx------+  4 sam    staff    148 Jul 28 11:43 Pictures
```

As with `Pictures`, `Music` should also have a `+` following the permissions. I'll worry about this if/when needed.